# Execute Script on mutliple computer from same Domain

Tags: windows, dns, execute

So I have a ton of computers that are all on the same domain. I would like to pick out a majority of those machines lets say 30 or so and execute a script that I wrote on all of them at once. Without having to go to each individual machine and execute it. I know the names of all the machines I would like to execute the script on, and they are all logged into the domain.

Is there a way this could be done?

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Create an OU in Active Directoy, move the computers that you want the script to run on into this OU, create a GPO that targets this OU, use the GPO settings to run your script on all computers in the OU. This is the RIGHT way to do this if you have an AD domain.

Comment: will I be able to use group policy if I am just planning on executing scripts on specific machines? and not everything in a group?

Comment: Absolutely. You can create an OU in AD (temporarily if you like) and move the computers into it. Then apply the gpo to that OU only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have another management system that could do this for you (like M$ SCCM, Symantec/Altiris), an easy and flexible (and free) option for remote execution is [Sysinternals' PSEXEC command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). To use it you would run a command like `psexec \\target1,\\target2 -u yourusername -p yourpassword -c yourscript.vbs`

Comment: I usually wrap the `psexec` call in a for loop, feeding it output from `net view`:   `net view /domain:(domain) > tmp.txt` // `for /F %i in (tmp.txt) do (psexec %i -u user -p pass -c script)`  The net view output needs a little massaging in between and can be substituted with a list of computer names from anywhere.

Comment: Yup, right on. I think you can just list the file in the psexec command like `psexec @tmp.txt -u...`, if that's any easier. I like to add a ping test before it tries the psexec to save time, too. :)

Comment: He's in an AD environment. The obvious solution is group policy.